# In what use case, if any, would one opt for the `_f` variants of Grand Central Dispatch in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

Based on Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) there are two flavors for GCD calls.

**"Block" Flavor.** The `dispatch_block_t` flavor which can use a standard Swift closure:

```
void dispatch_async( dispatch_queue_t queue, 
                     dispatch_block_t block );
```

Where the block "closure" allocates storage on the stack

```
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
```

**"Function" Flavor.**  The `dispatch_function_t` flavor which has a context object and a function pointer.

```
void dispatch_async_f( dispatch_queue_t queue, 
                       void *context, 
                       dispatch_function_t work );
```

The application-defined context object is passed to the dispatch function `work` as a `void *` object pointer parameter.

```
typedef void (*dispatch_function_t)(void *);
```

**Observations**
Empirically, the use of `_f` routines like `dispatch_async_f` and `dispatch_sync_f` in Swift are close to non-existant.

- [github search: dispatch_async_f language:Swift](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dispatch_async_f+language%3ASwift&type=Code&ref=searchresults)
- [github search: dispatch_sync_f language:Swift](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dispatch_sync_f+language%3ASwift&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Why not?

Are there any technical reasons or design patterns which justify considering the Grand Central Dispatch `_f` context+fuction variants in a Swift application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Objective-C and Swift have syntax that is compatible with the block/closure based API in GCD.  Given that the GCD API is low level and designed to work with other languages, the _f variants allow for passing a function instead (i.e., you could use them with a C language program).

To answer your actual question, there is probably no particularly good reason to use the function based API in Swift.  It's possible there is a performance win when using the _f variants, but unless you're dispatching many thousands of calls in a short period of time it would probably be negligible (and the over head of GCD/Run Loops might make this a bad approach for such things anyhow).

Comment: "thousands of calls" is a creative stretch for a use case.  Any other special cases come to mind, like maybe `dispatch_set_finalizer_f` (which does not have a block closure counterpart) used with `dispatch_set_context(queue, data)` ?? Thanks.

Comment: It's a creative stretch, but that probably illustrates the point (that you won't have much use for the _f API part of GCD).  The `dispatch_set_finalizer_f` function does not have a closure counterpart because it is primarily there so you can cleanup/`free` your `malloc`'d resources.  Closures in Swift and Objective-C use reference counting (automatic in Swift, manual or automatic in Objective-C) so it isn't particularly useful.  It's kind of like the callbacks that are available for `CFDictionaryRef` or `CFArrayRef` that allow you to `free` `malloc`'d things you store in them.

Answer (score 1):

In practical terms, there's zero use for the `*_f()` versions in Swift. But if you're writing C code, or pre-closure Obj-C, then they're the idiomatic way to perform callbacks, since closures aren't supported. Just do a GitHub search for those calls in C, and you'll, er, *see* what I mean. https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dispatch_async_f+language%3AC&type=Code&ref=searchresults

Comment: A general rule that *_f() versions are for non-closure languages is helpful.  Would you consider anything like `dispatch_set_finalizer_f` (which does not have a closure counterpart) as a notable or useful exception?  Thanks.

Comment: That one comes from BSD. According to [the docs](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/dispatch_set_finalizer_f/), "The dispatch_set_finalizer_f() specifies an optional per-object finalizer function that is invoked asynchronously if the context pointer is not NULL when the last reference to the object is released.  This gives the application an opportunity to free the context data associated with the object.  The finalizer will be run on the object's target queue." It sounds like a closure version of it wouldn't make any sense.